# Existence of k-plicates in the sequence A245788

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The sequence [A245788](https://oeis.org/A245788), "$n$ times the number of 1's in the binary expansion of $n$" ("times" here means multiplication), starts like this (starting with $n=1$):

```
1, 2, 6, 4, 10, 12, 21, 8, 18, 20,
33, 24, 39, 42, 60, 16, 34, 36, 57, 40,
63, 66, 92, 48, 75, 78, 108, 84, 116, 120,
155, 32, 66, 68, 105, 72, 111, 114, 156, 80,
123, 126, 172, 132, 180, 184, 235, 96, 147, 150,
204, 156, 212, 216, 275, 168, 228, 232, 295, 240, ...
```

I was curious about the duplicates in the sequence. A duplicate is defined as a number that appears at least twice in the given sequence, and a $k$-plicate is defined similarly as a number that appears at least $k$ times.

The first duplicate is $a(22) = a(33) = 66$, and the first triplicate is $a(1236)=a(1545)=a(2060)=6180$. It is not too hard to see that "if a $k$-plicate exists, then infinitely many $k$-plicates exist", since

$$
a(x_1) = a(x_2) = \dots = a(x_k) = y \\ \Rightarrow a(2x_1) = a(2x_2) = \dots = a(2x_k) = 2y
$$

But I'm not seeing a straightforward way to prove or disprove "a $k$-plicate exists for any $k \ge 2$".